# Get parent element in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to find the parent `tr` element when I use clicks a button on a `datepicker` calendar. Since I don't want to use jQuery **in the form of a script tag (edit)** in my Angular app, and this isn't possible using strictly CSS, I created the directive below. The `elm.find` is able to find and alter the css of the button correctly, so I know that I've found the element I'm looking for, however now I need to travel up the DOM.

I'm used to jQuery syntax, which doesn't work, and I haven't been able to find anything effective on the interwebs. Any chance someone could help me out with the syntax?

```
    /* Linker for the directive */
    var linker = function (scope, elm, attrs) {                   
        elm.on('click', function() {
            elm.find('table tbody tr button.active').parent('td').css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    };
```

**EDIT**

This is a directive that needs to be placed on a `uib-datepicker` element (Angular UI Bootstrap) in order to change alter the background-color for an entire row. The framework doesn't come with this functionality and the HTML isn't generated until the page loads.

I need to attach the directive to the element below, find the selected item and then work back up the DOM to find the parent `tr`.

```
<uib-datepicker highlightselectedrow class="well well-sm" ></uib-datepicker>
```

Comment: I think you should use `.closest` instead of `parent('td')` OR think of using `ng-class` if its feasible.

Comment: @PankajParkar .closest worked. If you want to add as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, I did, Thanks ;)

Comment: I *could* reproduce the scenario, but [could *not* get `.closest` to work in my repro](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXuspSkKCtQi9TbE0tWJ?p=preview). OP, can you help me understand how you got it to work and/or what's different in your situation from my repro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.parent` will look exact the upper `element` only. I'd say that rather use `.closest` so it will search in parent till it gets `td`

```
elm.find('table tbody tr button.active')
.closest('td').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: How did you get that to work? [I tried it but it didn't work for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXuspSkKCtQi9TbE0tWJ?p=preview), because the `.find(...)` doesn't actually seem to work in my repro. What's different? Could you extend your answer with a full working demo?

Comment: @Jeroen this is basically what I have. I had to modify it to include the `button` elements the datepicker uses like so: `elm.find('table tbody tr button.active').closest('tr').find('button').addClass('chosenReportWeek')`

Comment: Weird. I'd love to see a forked, updated plnkr that works, because as far as I can tell from [the relevant docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite) both `.closest` and `.find` with `.active` selectors aren't supposed to work with jQlite...

Comment: @Jeroen You're correct, to use `.closest` you need jQuery.. but `.find` does supported but you can do query DOM by tag name..

Comment: @Jeroen the problem with your plunkr was `.active` would not work with jQLite.. `.find` only look for tagname which are predefined. Selector and class based `.find` would not work with jQLite. my solution does need jQuery loaded before angular

Comment: Confusing, because OP says "*Since I don't want to use jQuery in my Angular app...*" in the question, but accepted the answer nonetheless. - @NealR are you sure that you're running this answer's solution *without* full jQuery?

Comment: @Jeroen oh.. that is my bad.. I should have read question before giving an answer.. basically I did comment and that works for OP, so he asked me add answer and I added it without seeing at original question..

Comment: @NealR could you please remove mark from answer so that I can delete my answer.. Are you sure you don't want to have jQuery in your application?

Comment: @PankajParkar let me clarify my post. I meant we didn't want to add the jQuery in a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about taking a more angular approach than psuedo jQuery? This is based on the [ngStyle Angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

```
<div ng-style="myStyle">Test</div>
<div ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'red'}">Click Me</div>
```

You would then place the `click` event on whatever element you want (td). The `ng-style` can be moved to what you want affected (tr).

Comment: Explanation added to the post why this wouldn't work